# How to delay a JavaScript JSON stream for one minute?

Tags: javascript, json

I am ask to write a java script program that retrieve an api JSON record from and address and through websocket every single minute. The stream continues after 60 seconds. I am expected to return the respective stream retrieve and the stream from the previous retrieve . Below is my code

```
var obj= 
{
    seconds : 60,
    priv : 0,
    prevTick : '' ,
    data : ''
}

function countTime()
{
    obj.seconds --;
    obj.priv ++;
    var msg ;
    if(obj.priv > 1)
    {
        obj.priv = 0;
        obj.msg = null;
    }
    if(prop.seconds < 0)
    {
        msg = sock.open();

        obj.msg = obj.msg + ", New Tick : " + msg.msg ; 
        setTimeout(countTime, 1000);
        obj.seconds = 60;
    }

}

var sock= new WebSocket('link');


sock.onopen = function(evt) {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({ticks:'string'}));
};

sock.onmessage = function(msg) {
   var data = JSON.parse(msg.data);
   return 'record update: %o'+ data ;

};
```

Please what is wrong with my code above ? It does not delay at all. The stream continues irrespective.

Comment: Use `window.setInterval("javascript function", milliseconds);` execute the function every x milliseconds specified

Comment: Thank you for the response sir. Do you perhaps see any problem with my code ? Its a test and dont have much time . This is the little i know. Please elaborate with code/answer .

Comment: Are you invoking `countTime()` somewhere outside of itself?

Comment: @Nico sir, No at the moment i am not. The requirement is, you can see the socket would return a stream message each time the message is send. I am to print the msg and delay the stream in to one minute. Also to print the stream and the one before it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about encapsulating the buffering behavior into a class?

```
function SocketBuffer(socket, delay, ontick) {
    var messages = [], tickInterval;

    socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
        messages.push( JSON.parse(msg.data) );
    };

    function tick() {
        if (typeof ontick !== "function") return;
        ontick( messages.splice(0) );
    }

    this.pause = function () {
        tickInterval = clearInterval(tickInterval);
    };
    this.run = function () {
        if (tickInterval) return;
        tickInterval = setInterval(tick, delay * 1000);
        tick();
    };
    this.run();
}
```

Note that `.splice(0)` returns all elements from the array and empties the array in the same step.

Usage:

```
var link = new WebSocket('link');
link.onopen = function (evt) {
    this.send( JSON.stringify({ticks:'string'}) );
};

var linkBuf = new SocketBuffer(link, 60, function (newMessages) {
    console.log(newMessages);
});

// if needed, you can:
linkBuf.pause();
linkBuf.run();
```

Comment: @Tomalak Sir i can see you  have two this.run in  your code. Please why the two seperate? Wouldnt one override the other ?

Comment: No. Have another look at the code. There is a difference.

Comment: @Tomalak you code is indeed well written and advanced. I don't understand where it log the previus record along with the new record. I have to log the new record along with a prev record. Thank you once more sir

Comment: @tomalak sir where do we defined our tickInterval ?

Comment: I am wrong sir if i add `tickInterval = setInterval(tick, delay);` ?

Comment: The function keeps all incoming messages in the `messages` array. Every N seconds it calls the `ontick` callback and passes any messages that have accumulated in the meantime. That's how I understood your requirement. I'm not sure what you mean by "prev record"?

Comment: @Tomalak sir, Its suppose to be by minute. So i suppose 3600 instead of 60 right ?  Also it suppose to print the record  or message of the previous minute sir.

Comment: @brickleberry You are right again, I missed the `* 1000`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function countTime() {
    var interval = 1000; // How long do you have to wait for next round
    // setInterval will create infinite loop if it is not asked to terminate with clearInterval
    var looper = setInterval(function () {
        // Your code here

        // Terminate the loop if required
        clearInterval(looper);
    }, interval);
}
```

Comment: sir, What do you think about my code? Would it deliver the requirement ? Its a test and have done all i know . Plus have to submit in few minutes.

Comment: Where did you call the countTime() function?

Comment: Sir only did called it in the steTimeout . Please can you correct me ? Where should i call it to control the delay ?

Comment: Well, you must at least call countTime once, before the recursive call to be able to triggered by setTimeout. Call it right after the definition of: var sock= new WebSocket('link'); would be a good choice.

Comment: Sir what if i put `window.setInterval(countTime(), 1000)`

Comment: Then you need to comment out this line: setTimeout(countTime, 1000);

Answer (score 0):

If you use `setTimeout()` you don't need to count the seconds manually. Furthermore, if you need to perform the task periodically, you'd better use `setInterval()` as @RyanB said. `setTimeout()` is useful for tasks that need to be performed only once. You're also using `prop.seconds` but `prop` doesn't seem to be defined. Finally, you need to call `countTime()` somewhere or it will never be executed.

This might work better:

```
var obj= 
{
    seconds : 60,
    priv : 0,
    prevTick : '' ,
    data : ''
}

function countTime()
{
    obj.seconds --;
    obj.priv ++; //I don't understand this, it will always be set to zero 3 lines below
    var msg ;
    if(obj.priv > 1)
    {
        obj.priv = 0;
        obj.msg = null;
    }
    msg = sock.open();
    obj.msg = obj.msg + ", New Tick : " + msg.msg; 
    obj.seconds = 60;
    //Maybe you should do sock.close() here
}

var sock= new WebSocket('link');

sock.onopen = function(evt) {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({ticks:'string'}));
};

sock.onmessage = function(msg) {
   var data = JSON.parse(msg.data);
   return 'record update: %o'+ data ;

};
var interval = setInterval(countTime, 1000);
```

**EDIT**: finally, when you're done, just do

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

to stop the execution.